# How to handle users without permission to access an app

Tags: error-message, error-prevention, permissions

**Background**: I work in Fintech. There are customers whose loans can become "written off" (due to high overdue balance etc.)Some of these customers use the customer app to access cool features. The business doesn't want to give these users permission to log in. Right now they can log in, but all the features are blank.

**Problem**: How might we tell a customer that their access has been revoked?

**My ideas**: Add a dialog over the log in page, landing page directing to the web portal which they still have access too.

Comment: Does the web portal require login?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes, both the native app and web portal share the same credentials for log in

Comment: Is there anything left that the user *can* do, going forward? Or is the business more or less severing ties with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time users log in after their native app access has been revoked bring them to a page that notifies them their access to the native app has been revoked, why, and how they can contact someone to get more information or sort out the problem.

On that same page assure them they still have access to the web portal.

Then, include a couple buttons, one stating something like:

```
[ I understand, take me to the web portal. ]
```

The other...

```
[ I need more information or help with this matter. ]
```

If `[ I understand... ]` is clicked, take them to the web portal.

If `[ I need more... ]`, take them to a detailed contact form or information page.

Record the fact either button has been clicked so upon any subsequent log-ins users can be taken directly to the web portal. Somewhere in the web portal, such as notifications, include access to a similar revocation notice.